# Advice on How to use Westside For Skinny Bastards

Tags: strength-training, training, programming

So, I am currently using [WS4SB3](https://www.defrancostraining.com/westside-for-skinny-bastards-part3/) and I have questions regarding the program.

1. Do I have to use the conditioning or can I just use the programs for 4 days without conditioning?
2. Can I modify the training program if I am not doing the conditioning part? I changed Jump Training to Squat for 3-4 of 8-12 Reps and I can see some good size gains on my quads.
3. My goal in the gym is to become a better athlete, is this program suitable for me or not?

Some prior information about me:
Novice,haven't been serious or consistent with regards to tracking progress.

1. Bench- 35+Weight of the Bar x 4 Reps
2. Squat- 46 kg x 2 Reps
3. OHP - 18.5 x 1 Rep

Comment: Your bench is higher than your squat? The f*** are you doing at the gym?

Comment: @nz_21 The Weight of the Bar is 7kg iirc so no.

Comment: The weight of an olympic bar is 20 kgs.

Comment: @nz_21Thats the neat part, it isn't an Olympic Bar.

Comment: You're using a lady bar? Use an Olympic bar mate

Comment: Also start doing deadlifts. And Eat more. Eat while you're programming. Eat before sleeping. Eat when you wake up. Pretty much the quickest way to get the lifts up

Comment: Not available in my "Fitness Club" @nz_21. Can't deadlift as well, floor is made of tiles, yeah I know , a shit ton of issue is there.

Comment: Buy one. And don't forget to curl and eat while you're shi**ing. The only true way to guarantee weight gain

Comment: If I had to buy one , I would rather make a home gym @nz_21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, you can do whatever you want. Want to remove the conditioning, sure you can! Want to change jump training for squats, no problem! Want to pull out pull ups and instead do bicep curls, of course! Want to remove the Monday max effort day and swap it out for an hour in a cafe sipping a soy latte, all you bro!

Thing is, you do any of that, then you're not running DeFranco's program, and you lose the right to claim you are.

If you want to try to follow the program, then you follow the program, as written, exactly as written (barring any **necessary** modifications; I once trained alongside a guy who'd lost an arm, he couldn't do the standard bench press, so he used a single dumbbell. THAT is a necessary modification). Follow it for a good few months. I haven't read the whole article, so I don't know how long he suggests running it, but whatever he says, do it.

You want to become a better athlete? Awesome! What's your sport?

Looking at your lifting numbers, you need to get stronger. A lot stronger. Be consistent, and pretty much any program should get you stronger. Also, you don't mention deadlift numbers at all, you should be deadlifting.

Ideally, if you want to be a better athlete, you want a basic strength program you can follow 3 days a week, training that doesn't leave you too sore, then you do skill work for your sport the other 4 days.

If you don't have a specific sport, then just follow the program, exactly as written, for a decent period of time (at least 3 months, ideally 6+) and see how it works for you.

If you want a program more specific to you, then hire a good trainer to write one for you, otherwise, just follow the program and don't modify it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.
I wanted to added a few details and answer some of your questions.
1. I don't do dead lift because of the Gym Restrictions, it is kind of like Planet Fitness where you don't have to make noise of dropping the weights on a dead lift, I do RDL's however.
2. My gym doesn't have a lot to equipment honestly, there is no Olympic Barbell ,Squat Rack etc , also I have just joined a company so I will start moving in a gym in 2-3 months, before that, this is what I have.
3. The sport I play is soccer and my goal physique would be that of a soccer player.